# Use method from class returned by interface java (spring bean)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Controller,that call inyected interface like this:

```
class controllerA{
    @Autowired
    public iService interfaceService;

    public void methodController(){
        String param1 = new String("example1");
        String param2 = new String("example2");
        this.interfaceService.getServiceA().methodA(param1,param2);
    }
}
```

Well, my interface is:

```
public interface iService {
    Class<T> getServiceA();
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class iServiceImpl implements iService {

    @Autowired      
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public class<T> getServiceA(){
        return appContext.getType("serviceA").cast(appContext.getBean("serviceA"));
    }
}
```

And the applicationContext-service.xml (1): (fixed)

```
<bean id="iServiceFacade" class="service.facade.iServiceImpl"/>

<bean id="serviceA" class="service.postgres.ServiceA"/>
```

And the applicationContext-service.xml (2) change this:

```
<bean id="serviceA" class="service.oracle.ServiceA"/>
```

These xml change with maven profile on compile time.

My problem is that it's not possible to call serviceA.methodA(param1, param2) on controller and I probe with distinct configuration.

The context inject the bean correctly, but how I call the method of the service on controller?

It's not possible to return on interface other interface implemented on serviceA, because the service have static method...

Thanks!

Comment: If the method returns a `Class<>`, how are you calling a method on it at all?!

Comment: "_because the service have static method_". `static` method  + Spring == something went very wrong along the way. Delete the `static` method and rethink your design.

Comment: Your code snippet is weird: `iServiceImpl` class with and id of `iServiceFacade` where you set the property `p:serviceA-ref="serviceA"` but the `iServiceImpl#getServiceA` retrieve the bean class programmaticaly. Is this a working code ?

Comment: inyect the serviceA on FacadeImpl is another probe. I obtain the bean by appContext.getBean("serviceA")

Comment: As an alternative to the suggestion of @BoristheSpider (deleting the static methods), you could also create wrapper classes that delegate to the static methods. That way you can create instances, which can then conform to a defined interface (e.g. `IServiceA`)